# Aptana 3 FTP Error Set Modification Time Failed

Tags: eclipse, ftp, save, aptana

This question was already posted but not answered. Upon saving I get the ftp error popup that says "failed to save the remote file due to exception " Set modification time failed ". Would you like to save the file locally instead. However, it does save it.

I am using Eclipse  3.7.2 with Aptana Studio 3 v3.4.0.2 ....

I am getting the nightly builds as some suggest and that didn't fix it. Not much out there to google yet.

Consequently , I have CFEclipse installed with it's own ftp which works fine for CF files on the same server. The site is a CF and PHP mix. FileZilla works fine as well.

If anyone was able to fix this I's be happy to know how. Just one of those slightly annoying little things. Tks

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm working in a office where, for a same project and server, some have this error coming up at each upload and others don't...

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues while working with a web site via FTP. It saves sometimes, but not others.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the files you are trying to save via ftp using putty/linux and type

```
ls -lart
```

the owner of the files might not be set to the right user.

```
sudo chown *user* -R /file/path/folder/
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: For me this error only happens 50% of the time, so if the owner was set wrong it would happen 100% of the time. Seems more like a bug in Aptana (but I'm not sure)